# Vector in Component Form

Tags: math-mode

[image: Vectors]

I am trying to write in component form, using \usepackage{amsmath}, \usepackage{amssymb} and \usepackage{amsbsy}. When I write \vij, there seems to be a mistake and the following appears. I downloaded an environments package online and I manage to write vectors in other forms quite well. If anyone could please advise where I went wrong it would be great!

FYI, the environments package include the following:

[image: Environments package] and [image: Environments Package 2]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Tex. Please do not post pictures of code, but the code itself. If possible, provide a MWE that compiles proberly or produces the error you have.

Comment: You also need `\usepackage{ifthen,xstring}`.

Comment: @Werner, got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macros use `\ifthenelse` conditionals supplied by [`ifthen`](//ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) and [`xstring`](//ctan.org/pkg/xstring). Include those in your preamble as well and things should compile as expected:

```
\usepackage{ifthen,xstring}
```